# Add padding to horizontal scroll box

Tags: html, css

The following code works as it should, but I'd like to have some padding on the right to give some space between the text and the border. The padding: 5px, puts padding on the top, left and bottom, but not the right. Everthing I've tried failed. Any suggestions?

```
#h-scrollbox {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #7a110f;
}
```

This code give me both a vertical and horizontal scroll bar, but no right margin. Putting it in a wrapper doesn't help.

> ## c-scrollbox {
>
> ```
> overflow-x: scroll;
> white-space:nowrap;
> width:100%;
> height:100px;
> padding: 5px;
> border: 1px solid #000000; }
> ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `padding: 5px` should work for all the sides! For a specific padding to the right try `padding-right: 30px`

Answer (score 1):

```
padding-right:5px;
```

Or if you want 5 everywhere and 10 on right :

```
padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
```

Comment: There should not be commas between the values.

Answer (score 1):

Your padding right will only be visible after having scrolled to the right if content is overflowing:

Try to add a wrapper arround your scrollable element in order to add more space :

```
#h-scrollbox-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid #7a110f;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#h-scrollbox {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

> [Live exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/svxu55v6/)

Comment: Adding the wrapper was the only and the ideal solution. Viva la France.

Comment: I'm fairly new to stackoverflow, so if this isn't the correct way to address this, please excuse me. Attempts to modify EdenSources's response to make the scroll box scroll both horizontally and vertically have been fruitless. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: OOPS!. Should have mentioned the failure is a lack of right margin. The box is scrollable both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Could you edit your question with new code if you are still stuck ? Or check the answer that helped you if problem is solved. Thanks ;)

Comment: EdenSource, please take a look at edited code.  Thanks.

Comment: I cannot get both horizontal and vertical scroll with your edited css code. And, I don't really understand what are you needs. Fact is, if your content is supposed to be horizontally scrolled, scroll length will extend while content is overflowing, so vertical scroll bar will never be used. What are you planning to do ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, EdenSource. The height of the scroll box is set to less than the height the text takes up. Therefore the need for a vertical scroll as well as the horizontal.

Comment: But, I'm sorry, if there is a horizontal scroll, text should only be on a single (long) line. And if text is multiple lines, horizontal scroll shouldn't exist. This is a concept I am not able to imagine. All apologies :(

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to wrap your #h-scrollbox into a container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="h-scrollbox">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
    commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus 
    et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam 
    felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla 
    consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet 
    nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, 
    venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
container {
width:90%; /* any value you like */
padding: 5px;
overflow:hidden;
border: 1px solid #7a110f;
}

#h-scrollbox {
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space:nowrap;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}
```

[See the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsrL8464/).

Answer (score -1):

As we can see here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

**padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;**

- top padding is 25px
- right padding is 50px
- bottom padding is 75px
- left padding is 100px

**padding: 25px 50px 75px;**

- top padding is 25px
- right and left paddings are 50px
- bottom padding is 75px

**padding: 25px 50px;**

- top and bottom paddings are 25px
- right and left paddings are 50px

**padding: 25px;**

- all four paddings are 25px

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, why right side paddding doesn't work for the OP.